# Some inequalities of real numbers

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, real-numbers

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_+:=\{ r \in \mathbb{R} \; ; \; r\geq 0\}$ arbitrary.

**Question 1.** By the triangular inequality, we have
$$|x+y| \leq |x|+|y| \Rightarrow |x+y|^2 \leq (|x|^2+2|x|\;|y|+|y|^2). \tag{1}$$
(Right?)

If $x,y \leq c$, for some $c>0$, then
$$|x+y|^2 \leq c^2+2c^2+c^2=4c^2?\tag{2}$$
Or $(2)$ hold only if $c>1$?

**Question 2.** Consider the number $xy \in \mathbb{R}_+$. If $x \geq 2$ then
$$2y \leq xy?$$

I think that this holds, since $y>0$. And so, we can multiplier $x \geq 2$ by $y>0$ in the two sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since $x,y\geqslant0$, you have $|x|=x$, $|y|=y$, and $|x+y|=x+y$. Therefore, the triangle inequality is not needed here. And, for any $c>0$, if $x,y\leqslant c$, you have$$(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2\leqslant4c^2$$(and not $3c^2$).
2. Yes: $x\geqslant2\implies xy\geqslant2y$, because $y\geqslant0$.

Comment: In Question 1 if $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|x|,|y| \leq c$ the $|x+y|^2 \leq 4c^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's the best conclusion that you can reach. Just see what happens if $x=y=c=1$.